# Azure Batch Node Inconsistent Folder Structure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-batch

I've been using an AzureBatch Pool for a while, with deployed application packages, and been able to modify/update them through Azure with no problems, for months.

I tried to create a new pool that is configured exactly the same as my current pool, but with a separate app package.

My problem is the folder structure is almost completely different between the two pools and I don't know what I can do about it.

The path for the original pool to the exes I need looks like:
C:\user\tasks\applications\wd\'packagename'\'version'\'nodetimestamp'\'PACKAGENAME'

But in this new pool the structure looks like:

C:\user\tasks\apppackages\'packagenameNodetimestamp'\'PACKAGENAME'

I cant see how these pools are created any differently, I've tried to recreate this new pool several times, but it comes out the same. Not all of the options when creating a pool are viewable from Azure Portal after it has been created, but I'm pretty sure it is just a cloudservices pool, windows server 2012 R2 for both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

EDIT:

Accepted answer is obviously correct. I had not updated my environment variable references to reflect the change in pools that I had made.

Comment: hey @DMarczak: quick question: How old was your old Pool? and for what instances do you need to physically check the file structure for the directory, Reason being if you use Azure batch level env vars: `Windows:
AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_APPLICATIONID#version`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages#execute-the-installed-applications you will have the lacation available to your running application.

Comment: Hello, my original pool was created in July. I am currently using `%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_'PKGNAME'%` as the root to my application folder structure.

If this is just the new way they will always be, I am fine to drop the old pool and recreate it, I am just worried about things continuously changing, or if I am creating these new pools incorrectly somehow.
Also, does this mean I have to have the app package version known at the batch job invocation site? With my original pool, the ENV variables would always point to the newest versions automatically.

Comment: Hmm apparently it is the same thing, I just need to update my string builder to have the correct 'APPLICATIONID' in the environment variable, as apposed to PKGNAME. The versioning still works the same, if you don't append/specify one, it uses the latest. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped! I will set this as answer post also add additional note below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages that you've specified for a pool or task are downloaded and extracted to a named directory within the `AZ_BATCH_ROOT_DIR` of the node. Batch also creates an environment variable that contains the path to the named directory. Your task command lines use this environment variable when referencing the application on the node.

On Windows nodes, the variable is in the following format:

Windows: `AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_APPLICATIONID#version`

On Linux nodes, the format is slightly different. Periods (.), hyphens (-) and number signs (#) are flattened to underscores in the environment variable. Also, note that the case of the application ID is preserved. For example:

Linux: `AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_applicationid_version`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages#execute-the-installed-applications

**Further to add**:

The internal mechanism and Dir structure is dependent on the OS type and IMO (In my opinion) it is no where recommened to be dependent on the hard coded location hence the mechanism to access these feature is via `env vars`, i..e whatever underlying changes may happen the `env vars` will point to the source of right dir.

If keen: There was an upgrade in place few months back and the feature notice is residing here: https://github.com/Azure/Batch/issues/1

Hope this covers the scenario and helps!

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, but I am to lowly and humble to give upvotes. Thanks again for helping me clear this up.